# __cxa_atexit could not be located in the dynamic link library autodock_gpu_128wi.exe

Tags: dll, makefile, build, opencl

I am building this git hub repository for [GPU acceleration in autodock](https://github.com/ccsb-scripps/AutoDock-GPU) from source. I have the Nvidia Development toolkit and can run the make command without issues (after modifying the make file to specify locations for the Cuda dependencies). However, when I try to run the .exe file that it creates it gives me this error: `__cxa_atexit could not be located in the dynamic link library autodock_gpu_128wi.exe`. What could be causing this issue? I think it should be compatible.

Machine:

- OS: Windows 10
- CPU: i7 9750H
- GPU: GTX 1650

Answer (score 0):

`__cxa_atexit` is a cxxabi in glibc

You need to check if linker has `-lc` by `-Wl,-v` argument for compiler.

If libc is not found by linker for some reason, you need to specify `libc.so.6`  path in glibc or just reinstall glibc.